# CakePHP Session timeout doesn't get executed

Tags: php, session, cakephp, timeout

I used the beforeFilter function to configure my timeout. However, it seems that it is not working. I know the standard is to put the session configuration in the core.php. However, because my requirements states that the value of the session timeout is configurable by the admin of the system we are developing.

below is a script

```
public function beforeFilter(){


        if ( $this->isStudent() ){
            $this->set('checkStatus',$this->checkComplete());   
        }

        parent::beforeFilter();
        //debug($this->Auth->user());
        //cakephp auth allow - allow all
        $this->Auth->allow('login','registerEmployee','registerCompany','forbidden','authorize','completeRegistration','registrationTnc','passwordReset','getUserData');

        // Set the Auth to global views
        if($this->Auth->user()){
            $this->set('activeUser',$this->Auth->user());
        }

        $settings = $this->Setting->find('first',array('fields'=>array('setting_max_session_timeout')));
        $sessionTimeout = $settings['Setting']['setting_max_session_timeout'];              

        Configure::write('Session', array(
            'defaults' => 'php',
            'timeout' => $sessionTimeout, //in minutes
            'cookieTimeout' => $sessionTimeout, //in minutes
        ));
    }
```

Comment: "_Doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description. What exactly doesn't work? Doesn't `CakeSession` use the defined values? Does `CakeSession::$sessionTime` contain an unexpected value? Does the session expire later/earlier than expected, or maybe never? ... btw, are the missing `$` for `sessionTimeout` just a typo in this code example? ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP Version!

Comment: 'Doesn't work' here refers to that the session timeout doesn't expire as expected. it expires later on. My cakephp version is 2.4 and the missing $ are mere typos.. I am eagerly waiting for any help

Comment: Unless by default the session timeout value is large - that can't work. The session will have already been accessed (and probably expired) by the time your beforeFilter code is run. ("Doesn't expire as expected" does not tell readers any more than "doesn't work", _in what way_? You need to be specific.)

Comment: Looks like you place that on UsersController.. You might try to place that on AppController...

Comment: in fact, the before filter that we defined here is actually in the app controller.